# test classes fail after updating a fields length and its datatype

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

Was given a task to update a fields data type and its length, I commented certain parts of the code to do the change as it mentioned the field was referenced in the Apex classes.

After the update certain test classes failed to execute with the message saying System.AssertException: Assertion Failed.

It is pointing out to the insert statement in the code -

```
Custom_Object__c customObjectInsert= new Custom_Object__c (
                Custom_Field__1 = 'Test 1',
                Custom_Field__2 = '1234 howard st Toronto ON',

        );
    
        Set<String> exceptions = new Set<String>();

        Test.startTest();
        try {
            insert customObjectInsert;
            System.assert(FALSE);
        } catch (Exception e){
            exceptions.add(e.getMessage());
        }

        Test.stopTest();
```

**Update**
Figured out the failure of the test classes had nothing to do with field update, as the developer was testing it to fail.

Comment: It looks to me as though you're testing for a specific exception being thrown: `System.assert(FALSE)`. My first thought is changing it to long text causes the field length to be OK but it's impossible to say for sure without knowing what you're intending to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because of `System.assert(FALSE);`. This means it's always going to fail. Usually, you wouldn't hardcode a boolean value when using `assert`. If you pass something into `assert` the test only passes if it's true. You can either do something more valuable with that assert, or remove it altogether.

Comment: You are right, the developer wanted it to fail.